# How to access createJS child from openFL framework?

Tags: html5-canvas, haxe, createjs, openfl, flash-cc

As I am targeting HTML5 using Adobe Flash CC, the resulted HTML5 output is based on createJS library.

Is it possible to use an openFL for HTML5 project to manipulate createjs based children that where exported from Flash CC ?

I want to make the best of the two worlds, to use Flash CC time line, and manipulate using haxe, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The content that is exported from Flash CC is just a JavaScript version of the Flash Library. For example, all library items are accessible on the global `libs` object. If you check out the exported HTML, it just creates an instance of your "main" symbol (usually named after your FLA), and stores it on `exportRoot`.

```
var exportRoot = new lib.Main_Symbol();
```

Using this approach it is super easy to create JS applications using Flash to create assets and animations.

I don't know how this applies to Haxe, but it has been architected to be very readable, reusable code.